# Add column mapping

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am facing an issue in dataflow where two or more columns coming from multiple files can have minor name variations but I need them to be considered as one column in the output. Something like this.
In source of dataflow
Say file1.csv has columns: column1, column2, column3
File2.csv has columns: column1, 2column, col3, column4
Now in my final output I need a way for dataflow to know that
I want clm1: column1, clm2: 2column or column2, clm3:column3 or col3, col4: anything containing column4

Also if for any of the output columns needed, a column doesn’t exist, say in File3.csv column1 doesn’t exit, clm1 would be null.

Final outcome should have clm1, clm2, clm3, clm4.

Is it possible in data factory?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Tho achieves this scenario like fuzzy mapping you need to use couple of Derived transformation and various mappings like `Column patterns` matching and rule based mapping.

Follow below steps to achieve your scenatio:

1. First here is my sample data for file1,csv as you provided in question
   [image]
2. Now you have to take derived transformation and create columns based on matching as per your source and destination column you have 1 common in first column of every file, 2 common for second column of every file and goes on so based on this we need to create column with column pattern matching.
   -- Will check on condition `like(name,'%1%')` whether column name contain 1 or not. give our destination column names as expected.
   [image]
   -- Data preview
   [image]
3. In data preview of derived column transformation click on `Map drifted` it will create another derived transformation with drifted columns ke[image: ep it as it is.]
4. Now take select transformation using **rule based mapping** create appropriate mapping as below:
   [image]

**Data preview and Output:**

[image]

***Now with auto mapping in sink transformation it will get mapped properly.***